# Display hyphen after 5 characters in text box for zip code - not working as expected

Tags: html, typescript, angular8

I have a requirement to display a hyphen after 5 characters in a text box for zip code. On entering more than 5 characters, a hyphen is displayed, as expected. However, when a user enters a hyphen symbol manually, the code should automatically remove the hyphen added manually. That is not working as expected. The hyphens added manually are not getting removed. When I debugged the typescript code in browser developer tools, I could see that the extra hyphen was removed from the property 'zipCode', but that change is not getting reflected in the UI.

Here is the code for the typescript file:

```
export class AppComponent {  

  zipCode: string = '';

  public setValue(val: any) {
    if(val.indexOf('-') >= 0)
      val = val.replaceAll('-', '');
    if(val.length > 5)
      val = val.substr(0,5) + '-' + val.substr(5, val.length - 5);
    this.zipCode = val;
  }
}
```

Here is the code for html file:

```
<input type="text" name="zipField" [(value)] = "zipCode" (input)="setValue($event.target.value)">
```

Can someone please let me know why this code is not working. Also, please suggest any alternate way of achieving the removal of extra hyphen added manually. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the `value` of the `input` alone you should pass the element itself.

That way you will be able to change the text in the `input` tag too

```
<input type="text" name="zipField" [(value)] = "zipCode" (input)="setValue($event.target)">
```

Then in your typescript file

```
export class AppComponent {  
  ...

  public setValue(element: any) {
    let val = element.value;

    if(val.contains('-'))
      val = val.replaceAll('-', '');
    if(val.length > 5)
      val = val.substr(0,5) + '-' + val.substr(5, val.length - 5);

    this.zipCode = val;
    element.value = val;
  }
}
```